# Delete cookie using array key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, cookies

Just wanna know how to delete cookies on PHP.
below are printed result of `$_COOKIES`.
So, I have an array of cart which store information as it suggested, and on my cart.php file I got a button to delete an agenda or options.

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [90406_cart] => Array
                (
                    [id_agenda] => 7
                    [qty_agenda] => 3
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [28962_option] => Array
                                (
                                    [id_option] => 3
                                    [qty_option] => 1
                                )
                            [52058_option] => Array
                                (
                                    [id_option] => 4
                                    [qty_option] => 1
                                )
                            [70617_option] => Array
                                (
                                    [id_option] => 5
                                    [qty_option] => 1
                                )
                        )
                )
            [86953_cart] => Array
                (
                    [id_agenda] => 17
                    [qty_agenda] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

The Question is how I can delete or unset this cookies from parent till child level of the array (let's say I want to delete agenda with key : `90406_cart` or `52058_option`)? 
Cookies was set using this script build on Codeigniter

```
$id_agenda = 1;

$qty_agenda = 20;

$option = array(1,2,3);

$qty_option = array(3,3,3);

$num = rand(10000,99999).'_cart';

$this->input->set_cookie('cart['.$num.'][id_agenda]',$id_agenda, 86400); 
$this->input->set_cookie('cart['.$num.'][qty_agenda]',$qty_agenda, 86400); 
for($i = 0; $i<count($id_option);$i++){     
    $num2 = rand(10000,99999).'_option';
    $this->input->set_cookie('cart['.$num.'][options]['.$num2.'][id_option]',$id_option[$i], 86400);        
    $this->input->set_cookie('cart['.$num.'][options]['.$num2.'][qty_option]',$qty_option[$i], 86400);      
}
```

Comment: Cookies can't handle much data so i think your getting cookie limits very soon using this

Comment: yes, typically the use case would only be around 2 or 3 agenda with maximum of 3 options per agenda so I think it should be okay.

`unset($_COOKIES['cart']['90406_cart'])` is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after experiment a bit using web development tools in chrome, I just realize that cookies was store in a row like :

```
cart[34705_cart][id_agenda] = 43
cart[34705_cart][qty_agenda] = 2
cart[34705_cart][options][12263_option][id_option] = 2
cart[34705_cart][options][12263_option][qty_option] = 4
```

Which mean it is stored in one row for each data and then PHP read it all as one variable with type of an `Array` which is practically impossible to delete / unset cookies just by using the array key like `unset($_COOKIES['cart']['90406_cart'])` or `$this->input->set_cookie('34705_cart')` . The solution I came up is like this:

```
// delete all cookies for agenda and including any options on the agenda array
$array_key = '34705_cart';
$this->input->set_cookie('cart['.$array_key.'][id_agenda]'); 
$this->input->set_cookie('cart['.$array_key.'][qty_agenda]'); 
foreach($data[$array_key]['options'] as $key => $item){
    $this->input->set_cookie('cart['.$array_key.'][options]['.$key.'][id_option]'); 
    $this->input->set_cookie('cart['.$array_key.'][options]['.$key.'][qty_option]'); 
}

// delete option on the agenda
$array_key = '34705_cart';
$array_key2 = '12263_option';

$data = $this->input->cookie('cart');

$this->input->set_cookie('cart['.$array_key.'][options]['.$array_key2.'][id_option]');
$this->input->set_cookie('cart['.$array_key.'][options]['.$array_key2.'][qty_option]');
if(count($data[$array_key]['options'][$array_key2]) == 1){
    $this->input->set_cookie('cart['.$array_key.'][options]');
}
```

I hope this help someone who maybe tumbling on case like this one.